# Redirect URL Using ".htaccess"

Tags: .htaccess

I am having a issue redirecting my URL to another URL. I have tried 4-5 ".htaccess" codes but they were not helpful.

I want to redirect "m.onlinedealsindia.in/?page=0" to "m.onlinedealsindia.in/?page=1".

Hope to get a helpful answer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =m.onlinedealsindia.in
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=0$
RewriteRule ^/?$ ?page=1 [L,R=302]
```

Comment: its giving url - http://m.onlinedealsindia.in/home/onlinede/m.onlinedealsindia.in/?page=1